# Nutch updatedb WrongRegionException

Tags: hbase, nutch

I run generate-fetch-parse and after update I got this exception.

```
2014-01-23 13:40:56,905 ERROR store.HBaseStore - Failed 747 actions: WrongRegionException: 747 times, servers with issues: server.eu:43556, 
    2014-01-23 13:40:56,905 ERROR store.HBaseStore - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@12101d00
```

Can you please help me to understand where can be problem?

using versions: Nutch 2.2.1, Hbase 0.90.6

Comment: I solved this finally with different versions. Nutch 2.3 (from trunk) and HBase 0.90.4

Comment: Can you specify the reason why it is happening

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know what causes this problem in this combination of versions.